# Apply function to specific element's value of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
tbl_headers = db_admin.execute("SELECT name, type FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(?);", table_name)
```

`tbl_headers` is same below:

```
[{'name': 'id', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'abasdfasd', 'type': 'TEXT'}, {'name': 'sx', 'type': 'TEXT'}, {'name': 'password', 'type': 'NULL'}, {'name': 'asdf', 'type': 'TEXT'}]
```

I need apply `hash_in()` function on the `'name'` values are in dictionary elements of above list.

### Have tried these:

```
tbl_headers = [hash_in(i['name']) for i in tbl_headers]
```

suppresses dictionaries and return only a list of 'name' values:

```
['sxtw001c001h', 'sxtw001c001r001Z001e001c001r001Z001a001Z', 'sxtw001w001r', 'sxtw001c001q001n001v001r001r001Z001o', 'sxtw001e001c001r001Z']
```

OR

```
tbl_headers = map(hash_in, tbl_headers)
```

Returns error.

### Update

The Output result I have seek is same:

```
[{'name': hash_in('id'), 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': hash_in('abasdfasd'), 'type': 'TEXT'}, {'name': hash_in('sx'), 'type': 'TEXT'}, {'name': ('password'), 'type': 'NULL'}, {'name': ('asdf'), 'type': 'TEXT'}]
```

Appreciate you.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output/end result you seek?

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: `<map object at 0x7fe87c95a860>` (No results more this!)

Comment: Since you are looking to update the dictionaries, I would be strongly tempted to just use a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: @JonSG, As python strange availability  are there, is there possible simple and more straight way to run function with situational on the intended dictionary items are wrapped in a list? I though may have some notations in map() or comprehensions or lambda functions.

Comment: Do you want to modify the original list/list items or do you want to create a new list and or new items?

Comment: @parmer_110: That's how [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) works in Python3, that's not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```py
tbl_headers = [{'name': hash_in(i['name']), 'type': i['type']} for i in tbl_headers]
```